# What do Rear-End Collision Avoidance System do on Ice?

Tags: electrical, brakes

I read on [itworld.com](http://www.itworld.com/article/2826935/networking/11-cutting-edge-car-tech-innovations.html?page=3):

> Companies such as Volvo and Mercedes are working on crash avoidance systems. Radar measures the distance to obstacles ahead of the car, and if one comes too close the system will warn the driver. If the driver fails to act in sufficient time to stop the car safely, the cars computer takes over and applies the brakes.

Is anyone working on making the cars respond sooner at colder temperatures, or when the road appears to be in slippery conditions? (car has less traction, etc.)

Comment: @CharlieRB, a quick glance at recent posts returns: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38949/what-is-an-igniter, http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38938/why-does-using-the-low-range-of-a-4wd-transmission-give-better-acceleration, http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38913/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-microphone-placed-at-rear-view-mirror.  I want to do things right, but honestly, what's the difference?

Comment: @CharlieRB - IMHO, this question is on-topic for the site, though possibly a bit broad. We've had many other questions which ask about how a car or car system works, but not necessarily trying to fix an issue. I've asked the question over on [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to see if there is any real heartburn about it.

Answer (score 1):

If the vehicle is equipped with ABS, computer control will be able to apply the brakes with a reasonable expectation that the vehicle will stop. And since most vehicles today are equipped with outside temperature sensors, the computer will know when ice should be expected (outside temperature below freezing) and apply the brakes sooner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was asking if anyone is actually working on it.  Do you have any sources?